# Is the result from an 'OR' clause in SQL SELECT defined?

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, hana

What I mean is this:

If I have SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = ('VAL1' OR 'VAL2') AND ...
```

If the table in question has entries for both 'VAL1' and 'VAL2', does the order in the WHERE clause make any difference?

If I would prefer to get back a record with 'VAL1' but would take 'VAL2' if the former is not available, will the above SELECT guarantee this? Or is the response undefined in this case? And would this behavior furthermore perhaps be vendor-specific?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Is is SAP HANA.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it this way, it could return wrong record depending in where and order.

Try :

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 
WHERE (COL1 = 'VAL1' OR (COL1 = 'VAL2' and (select count(*) from tab1 where COL1 = 
'VAL1') = 0)) AND ...
```

Comment: `where (select count(*)) = 0` is massively worse than `where not exists`.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `UNION ALL`. Let the first `SELECT` return VAL1 rows. Have another `SELECT` that returns VAL2 rows, but only if there exists no VAL1 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1
WHERE COL1 = 'VAL1'
union all
SELECT * FROM TAB1
WHERE COL1 = 'VAL2'
  and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = 'VAL1')
```

Basically the same as @Claudio Biselli's answer, but easier to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for ranking the results on the basis of preference and then choosing the records which are most preferred as below

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by case when col1='VAL1' then 1 
                                         when col1='VAL2' then 2
                                    end asc) as rnk  
  FROM TAB1 
 WHERE COL1 = ('VAL1' OR 'VAL2') 
 )X
WHERE X.RNK=1
```

Comment: Order in the WHERE clause is not going to make a difference, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use **IN** instead of OR

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 IN ('VAL1','VAL2') AND ...
```

Comment: The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

Comment: That does not answer the question though. Is there a guaranteed order to the results and can it be influenced by the order in the OR clause?

Answer (score 0):

All conditions in a `WHERE` clause are applied simultaneously in SQL. There is no order guaranteed or implied at all. This is true for any SQL DBMS, not just SAP HANA.

To have a weighted selection criterion you need to create a weighting function, just as the other replies indicated.
One approach, that is rather easy to implement, is to first create `SELECT`s for all possible weights and then choose the entries with the highest/lowest weight.

For example:

```
WITH weighted AS ( 
 SELECT 100 as SEL_WEIGHT, PK1, PK2 
 FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = 'VAL1'
UNION ALL
 SELECT 60 as SEL_WEIGHT, PK1, PK2 
 FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = 'VAL2'
UNION ALL
 SELECT -1 as SEL_WEIGHT, PK1, PK2 
 FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 IS NULL)

SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    weighted 
WHERE (PK1, PK2, SEL_WEIGHT) in
      (SELECT PK1, PK2, MAX(SEL_WEIGHT) as MAX_WEIGHT
       FROM weighted
       GROUP BY PK1, PK2);
```

In this example, the sub-select finds the maximum weight and the related primary key columns (`PK1`, `PK2`) and joins them back as the final selection criterion to the main `SELECT`.
Records with `COL1 ='VAL1'` are weighted highest (100) and preferred over those with `COL1='VAL2'` (60) or those where `COL1` is `NULL` (-1).

The benefit of such a construct is that it is easy to see how the weights are defined and that each weight can have its own independent combination of conditions.

As weighted selection criteria are non-standard in SQL systems I highly recommend making the implementation as obvious as possible to avoid confusion and misunderstanding later on.